# How to fix view shrinking completely after putting too much text in Multiline Text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, indexoutofboundsexception

In Android Studio my whole view shrinks to the upper left corner completely. This happens when I put too much text in a Multiline Text. I also get these errors `View measure failed` and `Exception raised during rendering`. When I click on details they both show `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16`.

I've tried using different API's and the same thing happened.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455377/android-multiline-edittext-shrinks-disorients-background-when-text-entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*FIXED*
I fixed it by going to the xml editor and manually moving the text to the new line after it got too wide. For some reason if the text is too long and it doesn't have enough breaks it throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16.`